# What happen if two websites redirect its users to each other?

Tags: webserver, website, redirection, web, hosting

Let's say we have *x.com* and *y.com*

*x.com* redirects to *y.com*

while *y.com* redirects to *x.com*

**will users be redirected forever? or what will happen?**

Comment: Redirections are processed by the client (i.e. the browser). Most modern browsers just give up after some maximum number of redirections (20 or so).

Answer (score 2):

You will probably just get the error

> Too many redirects

and nothing further will happen.
It's not something I'm ever likely to test empirically.